# Mouseover effect on JTable cell

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently having difficulty on adding mouse-over effect to all cells of particular column. The problem is when adding mouse listener to table, the cell-inner component doesn't get mouse event while cursor is hovering over that cell. Could you please tell me where is problem?

Comment: Posting your code, or an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), will help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, the cell widgets are only temporarily used to paint themselves over the correct area but i don't think they are active othewise. You should try listening to the JTable and then you can find back which cells have been clicked with `rowAtPoint` and `columnAtPoint()`.